# error in webrat

Tags: enums

> duplicate of [Error in webrat installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659586/error-in-webrat-installation)

hai all,
       i am getting an error when i am iinstalling webrat for my rails app.i want to use in my rails app cucumber, rspec,webrat to my app test.so please give me some solution to this error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing webrat:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659586/error-in-webrat-installation - duplicated question and user.

Answer (score 0):

try  `apt-get install libxslt-dev`